# sql database design for ecommerce

Tags: sql, database, e-commerce

**I am working on e-commerce website.
I have 3 levels of categories**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `parent_categories` (
      `parent_cat_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `parent_cat_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
      `created_on` datetime NOT NULL,
      `updated_on` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      `status` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT '1=0 active ',
      PRIMARY KEY (`parent_cat_id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=49 ;



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `child_categories` (
  `child_cat_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `child_cat_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `parent_cat_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_on` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_on` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`child_cat_id`),
  KEY `fk_parent_cat_id` (`parent_cat_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=64 ;



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sub_child_categories` (
  `sub_child_cat_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sub_child_cat_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `child_cat_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_on` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_on` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sub_child_cat_id`),
  KEY `fk_child_cat_id` (`child_cat_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=53 ;
```

**This is my products table**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_cat_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `child_cat_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sub_child_cat_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `sku` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `brand` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `discount` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tax` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`),
  KEY `p_id` (`parent_cat_id`),
  KEY `ch_id` (`child_cat_id`),
  KEY `sub_ch_id` (`sub_child_cat_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

**Now My doubt is , how to design table for storing product specifications based on categories**

For example Consider Two Categories:

1. Fashion
2. Food

In Fashion

1. clothing->Shirts  : **color,material,size,sleeves,size chart**
2. footware->Shoes    : **color,material,size,size chart**
3. ethenic->Shawl    : **color,material,size**
4. Body care->perfume  : **price based on weight**

In Food

1. Sweet    : **color,Price based on weight**
2. pickels->veg : **Price based on weight**

Comment: did you find the solution ?

Answer (score 1):

ok lets take:

color,material,size

now imagine you have a product like a Soccer team t-shirt. and this shirt comes in 3 different colors, and 4 different sizes. 3 x 4 = 12 variations. so there is one link to a page that has a picture and description of a Soccer team t-shirt. AND there are 12 different variations of that shirt available for sale.

the most critical point - each variation is going to have separate inventory and if you are selling somewhere like amazon - separate UPC or EAN codes. so the most practical thing is to have a database record for each variation, and that database record must contain the attributes of size, color, price, inventory on hand, etc etc.

so then that leads to the idea of Parent - Child Products. the product that we see on the page is the Parent product. the actual shirts that vary by size, color, etc - those are the Child products. heres more info from amazon seller central http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html/?nodeId=200779220